# how to get the page number inside content (html layout) of kartik mpdf

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I am using **Kartik mpdf** library to generate pdf. I am generating barcode in the body of the pdf which contains mcqs question generated through loop so pages are inserted randomly depending on the questions, So I need the page number to be set in my barcode on each page.

**Kartik mpdf** provides a method `'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}|']` which gives page number in footer but this `{'PAGENO'}` is not working in my html document... How would I get the page number inside my document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAGENO has nothing to do with kartik, is from [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-numbering.html). When you say is not working in your html, that's because that placeholder variable is going to be parsed with mpdf, so if you are not generating a pdf it wont take effect.

On the other hand, you can't show the page number in your html. There's no pages numbers on a html document, as it will depend in the page size and the font size of the browser, so it won't be possible to know "where you are" on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using renderPartial method. Please find my code below.

```
 $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_UTF8, // leaner size using standard fonts
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'content' => $this->renderPartial('print', [
            'model' => $model,
            'quotations' => $modelQtn,
            'pageNo' => ['{PAGENO} of {nb}'],
        ]),
        'filename' => $model->po_no,
        'cssFile' => [
            '@vendor/../backend/assets/css/custom-style.css',
            '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',

        ],
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '
        .kv-heading-1 {
            font-size:26px
        }
        .text-center {
            font-family : Arial !important;
            font-size:
        }',
        'options' => [
            // any mpdf options you wish to set
            'title' => 'Purchase Order'
        ],
        'methods' => [
            'SetTitle' => $model->po_no,
            'SetSubject' => 'Mohammed Iqbal Khan',
            'SetHeader' => [ 'Generated On: ' . date("F j, Y, g:i a")],
            'SetFooter' => ['|Page {PAGENO} of {nb}|'],
            'SetAuthor' => 'Mohammed Iqbal Khan',
            'SetCreator' => 'Mohammed Iqbal Khan',
            'SetKeywords' => 'Mohammed Iqbal Khan',
            'SetWatermarkText' => 'DRAFT',
            'SetWatermarkImage' => '',

        ]
    ]);
    return $pdf->render();
```

Once you pass the page no method, then you can use the below code to show page no in your document while generating.

```
<?= $pageNo[0];?>
```